# Как подключить датчик MH-Z19B к Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

У меня обычный Raspberry Pi 3.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И мне нужно подключить датчик MH-Z19B желательно на выбранных pin.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вывести это всё в консоль Raspberry Pi
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу найти подходящую библиотеку, они либо не работают, либо даже не запускаются. Код нужен в python

Мне нужно подключить этот датчик, и вывести его на экран. Что бы он выводил значения по команде. Желательно указывать pin подключения свои. Так как для конкурса у меня ещё есть куча датчиков которые используют TX и RX pin.
Я даже пытался понять как он работает, но для меня это как то сложно. Я не могу создать свою библиотеку.

Answer (score 0):

Про подключение и съём показаний очень подробно описано тут:

https://gadgetpage.ru/instrukcii/3279-testirovanie-modulja-infrakrasnogo-datchika-co2-mh-z19.html

"Вывод на экран"  - на кокой экран? На малинке, или на РС? Если хотите без геммороя, то просто пишите показания в CSV файл а потом, хоть в R хоть в Mathlab выводите в какой угодно форме.

Comment: Ничего не работает! Просто выводит ошибку

Comment: - "Ничего не работает! "
- "Товарищи учёные! Третий год у меня в подполье происходит подземный стук. Объясните мне, в чём дело?"

А можно подробнее -  что именно не работает? Источник питания не включается? Лампочки не горят? 

 - "Просто выводит ошибку"
1. Кто выводит ?
2. Какую конкретно ошибку ?